# Is ROS2 going to support Python 3 and C++14?

Tags: python, ros2, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My main question is in the title.

If these languages versions are not going to be supported, what are there the main reasons that prevent it from happening? What would be the libraries that are only supported for Python 2.7 and <=C++11 but not for the new versions of the programming languages, that the ROS team would like to include anyway in the system?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260603/is-ros2-going-to-support-python-3-and-c++14?/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2017-04-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2017-04-28**:
Probably yes. See this github wiki: https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This page](http://design.ros2.org/articles/changes.html) currently says the following:

> **C++ standard**
>
> The core of ROS 1 is targeting C++03
> and doesn’t make use of C++11 features
> in its API. ROS 2 uses C++11
> extensively and uses some parts from
> C++14. In the future ROS 2 might start
> using C++17 as long as it is supported
> on all major platforms.
>
> **Python**
>
> ROS 1 is targeting Python 2. ROS 2
> requires at least Python version 3.5.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5